# Having several apps for the same package

Tags: android, build, continuous-integration, hockeyapp

According to [documentation](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-apps) `Hockeyapp` distinguish one app from another comparing `packages`. Is it possible to upload apks with same package but as different apps?

Initial problem: I have several branches(`feature/x`, `feature/y`, etc) so I would like to upload all feature branches and testers could download apk from a particular branch.

Comment: Please try product flavor in gradle with android studio

Comment: @lal `product flavors` are not for feature/fix branches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple apps on HockeyApp with the same package name.

You can do this by [manually creating](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-apps#create-app) the app on HockeyApp first and then uploading the build to that specific app using the [Upload Version API](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-versions#upload-version).